# Custom sort order in Access report

Tags: ms-access

I’m working with a golf database. Most of the reports are grouped by players and sorted by holes 1 to 18.
However, in some cases, I would like to sort the report by holes like 10 11 … 18 1 2 …. 9 (= actual order the holes are played). Again I’m running out of ideas and any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Is there any other column in the table that indicates eg the time the hole was played so you could use that one? And as my knowledge of golf is nonexisting: are holes always played in that order? If so, you could maybe add a column eg playorder that contains 1 for hole 10, 2 for hole 11, etc?

Comment: Thanks fvu. You lead me to the beginning of a path which helped me to find a solution.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably looking for a sort expression like this:

```
=([hole]+18-[StartHole]) Mod 18
```

Comment: Thanks Wolfgang. This is even better.